# Как получить N комбинаций элементов списка JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, математика

Как можно на JS получить все n комбинаций элементов списка list?

Например, дан список `list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` и `n=4;`
В итоге должно быть: `[[1,2,3,4], [1,3,4,5], [1,2,4,5], [2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,5]]`

Число элементов в списке list может быть любым, как и число n.
Индекс элементов не важен, то есть не должно быть повторов на подобии: `[1,2,3,4] и [2,1,3,4]`, а также не должны повторяться элементы, например если дан список `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` не должно быть `[1, 2, 3, 4] и [1, 1, 3, 4]`, а вот если бы был дан изначально список `[1, 1, 3, 4, 5]`, то такое такое повторение возможно.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, вам нужны комбинации без повторений. Краткая теория: https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/tree/master/src/algorithms/sets/combinations Как минимум две реализации см. в популярных репозиториях с примерами алгоритмов на JS: https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/algorithms/sets/combinations/combineWithoutRepetitions.js или https://github.com/mgechev/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/combinatorics/combinations.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном алгоритме получаем все возможные комбинации элементов в виде массива двоичных чисел, например:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '0'] что соответствует массиву [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const count = 4;

const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const count2 = 3;

const fromBinaryPosition = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, item, index) => (item === '1' ? [...acc, array[index]] : acc), []
  );

function getCombinations(array, count) {
  const maxNumber = parseInt(
    ''.padStart(count, '1').padEnd(array.length, '0'),
    2
  );
  const indexedArray = [];
  const minItem = parseInt(''.padStart(count, '1'), 2) - 1;

  for (let i = maxNumber; i >= minItem; i--) {
    const n = i.toString(2);
    if (n.split('1').length - 1 === count) {
      indexedArray.push(n.padStart(array.length, '0').split(''));
    }
  }

  return indexedArray.map(fromBinaryPosition);
}

console.log(getCombinations(array, count));
console.log(getCombinations(array2, count2));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не подскажите почему если я меняю входные данные на `const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]; let count = 3` получаю вот такое `[Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [2, 3, 4]
1: (3) [2, 3, undefined]
2: (3) [2, 4, undefined]
3: (3) [3, 4, undefined]
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`  undefined не пойму почему получается

Comment: у меня array будет содержать от 3 до 20 элементов, как целых так и дробных, а count будет может быть от 2 и до 19, если это имеет значение

Comment: в том числе повторяющихся `const array = [1, 2, 3, 4.8, 5, 5];`

Comment: не знаете как можно исправить?

Comment: Вроде как разобрался, нужно в строке `indexedArray.push(n.padStart(5, '0').split(''));` изменить `5 на array.length или 3`. Спасибо)

Comment: @ChikChirik спасибо за исправление ошибки, исправил ответ

Answer (score 3):

На enSO похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241174/javascript-generating-all-combinations-of-elements-in-a-single-array-in-pairs) уже задавался, можно там поискать.

```js
function combination(item, n) {
  const filter = typeof n !== 'undefined';
  n = n ? n : item.length;
  const result = [];
  const isArray = item.constructor.name === 'Array';

  const pow = (x, n, m = []) => {
    if (n > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const value = pow(x, n - 1, [...m, isArray ? item[i] : i]);
        result.push(value);
      }
    }
    return m;
  }
  pow(isArray ? item.length : item, n);

  return filter ? result.filter(item => item.length == n) : result;
}

console.log(combination([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно без повторов

Comment: ваш код дает на выходе не 5 комбинаций, а больше из-за повторов.

Comment: Можете просто удалить [дубликаты](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/array/javascript-remove-duplicates-from-array/)

Comment: а как добавить такое условие по удалению дубликатов?)

Comment: можете тупо по результату циклом пройтись, я код из ответа на enSO же скопировал.